# User guidance via error messages displayed in the scenarios in which user provides the same Email Address

Tags: error-message

There is a functionality in the system for inviting users in bulk. For inviting users, the admin has to provide the email addresses of the users.

Case 1: If an existing email address is entered, the error message shown is

> "This email address is already associated with an account."

Case 2: User enters the same email address for 2 or more users, the error message in my mind is:

> "Duplicate email address provided."

- Do these messages provide clarity on what the issue is to the user?
- Do these messages draw a clear line between the two scenarios or is there room for improvement?
- Do we also need to specify the next action use can take for correcting the errors (i.e. Enter correct email ID)?

Comment: What are the negative consequences of submitting duplicate emails? Is it important enough to encumber the process with error messages?

Comment: assuming the messages are necessary, what's wrong with using "This email address is already associated with an account." for both errors? The cause is the same, the result is the same, and the remedy is the same.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Email ID is the unique identifier for each user so when inviting users in bulk, one cannot provide the same email for two users to invite them. And if an action is prohibited for the user, I believe its important to inform him as to why he cannot perform a certain action.

Comment: @RouxMartin Because when providing the same email address for two users, it might be that the email address provided is not linked with an already existing account. Hence, the second toast message.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the second message would only occur if a user enters an email address that exists in the database but does not have an account linked - surely that's a technical/data problem and not a UX problem? if that's occurring on a regular basis then something else is broken and the message will not fix that.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing how duplicate emails are the user"s problem, and not a simple programming response to skip them. You're focusing on the name, I suggest don't give it much weight, focus on the email, and simply skip duplicates.

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough details, but there are general guidelines for error messages that you can follow: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/